# Сортировка по зависимостям.

Tags: алгоритм

У меня есть такая задача.

У меня есть не отсортированный список объектов, зависящих друг от друга. Зависимости могут быть двух видов: обязательные и необязательные.

После сортировки список должен принять такой вид: для каждого элемента все его обязательные зависимости должны идти раньше, чем он сам. Если возникает циклическая зависимость, или обязательная зависимость отсутствует в исходном списке, элемент удаляется / бросается исключение. Необязательные зависимости по возможности инициализируются до зависимых элементов, но если это невозможно – то в конец ставятся компоненты, от которых зависит как можно меньше других элементов.

В принципе, что-то похожее есть в Autofac, но там создание графа объектов и инициализация объекта не разнесены, а мне нужно эти операции разнести.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не рассматривать необязательные зависимости, то ваша задача является задачей нахождения [топологической сортировки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). Насчет необязательных зависимостей - топологическая сортировка определяется неоднозначно, поэтому можно как-то пошевелить результат, чтобы минимизировать количество невыполненных зависимостей, но точно не скажу.